# I want to create a double layered pie / donut chart in R

Tags: r, pie-chart, gplots

and I am trying to create a double layered pie, here is my data:

```
winner            <- c("White"   , "draw"    , "Black")
lowrated_scotch1  <- c(0.56617647, 0.04411765, 0.38970588) #winrate for Whites,Draws,Blacks in chess
highrated_scotch1 <- c(0.50000000, 0.03676471, 0.46323529)
```

To give more context, i'm trying to visualize the difference in winrate between whites/draws/blacks for a highrated/lowrated players in Chess for the Scotch opening from the data I already managed to gather.

This is what I have in mind :(image taken from google image)

[layered pie chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7VHr.png).

This is my code :

```
multi_layer_scotch<-data.frame(winner = c("White","draw","Black"),
                               Y = c(highrated_scotch),
                               X = c(lowrated_scotch))


ggplot(multi_layer_scotch, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = winner))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#769656","#baca44","#eeeed2"))+
  coord_polar(theta="y")+
  theme_void()
```

and this is what i'm getting as an output :

[my marvelous not complete graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghe3J.png)

As you can see, the graph isn't layered the way I want. The 3 layers from my plot should be assembled in one layer (to represent the lowrated payers) stacked with another layer (representing the highrated players).

I tried to follow the solution given in this post , but I couldn't manage to do it myself, I felt like it was a little incomplete : [Multi-level Pie Chart in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300767/multi-level-pie-chart-in-r)

I'de be glad if you could help me with this! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean something like this:

```
df1 <- melt(multi_layer_scotch)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = winner))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  coord_polar(theta="y")
```